# row number increases by specific conditions in more fast way R

Tags: r

The data frame I have looked like this.

[image]

"rank" variable has to be increased once the differences between the [i]th row of "start" and the [i-1]th row of "end" are over 14.(also, when encountered the different "ID")

I tried the code below and it worked very well.

But the thing is.. it is way too slow because I have like over 700000 rows.

So, is there any way to make it perform much faster?

```
df$rank <- 1

for(i in 2:nrow(l50.df)){
  df[i,"rank"] <- ifelse((df[i,"ID"]==df[i-1,"ID"])&
                                   (df[i-1,"diff"]<=14), 
                         df[i,"rank"] <- df[i-1,"rank"],
                         df[i,"rank"] <- df[i-1,"rank"] + 1)
}
```

Comment: Pleaase do not include images of your data, but privide a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: did you try dplyr? df <- df %>% mutate( rank = ifelse( (ID == lag(ID) ) & (lag(diff) <= 14), rank, rank+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(rank  = cumsum(diff > 14 | ID != lag(ID, default = TRUE)))
```

Same logic using base R :

```
df$rank <- with(df, cumsum(diff > 14 | c(TRUE, tail(ID, -1) != head(ID, -1))))
```

Comment: I solved the problem with a little application of your solution Thanks: ```df <- df %>% 
  mutate(rank  = cumsum((start - lag(end, default = TRUE)) > 14 | ID != lag(ID, default = TRUE)))```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cumsum` to get an *increasing rank* when the *conditions* `df[i,"ID"]==df[i-1,"ID"]) & (df[i-1,"diff"]<=14)` are meet.

```
df$rank <- cumsum(c(1,(df$ID != c(df$ID[-1], NA) | df$diff>14)[-nrow(df)]))
df
#   ID diff rank
#1   a    4    1
#2   a    6    1
#3   a    8    1
#4   a  870    1
#5   a   34    2
#6   a   NA    3
#7   b    4    4
#8   b    6    4
#9   b    8    4
#10  b  870    4
#11  b   34    5
#12  b   NA    6
```

Using your code:

```
df$rank <- 1
for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
  df[i,"rank"] <- ifelse((df[i,"ID"]==df[i-1,"ID"]) & (df[i-1,"diff"]<=14), 
    df[i,"rank"] <- df[i-1,"rank"], df[i,"rank"] <- df[i-1,"rank"] + 1)
}
df
#   ID diff rank
#1   a    4    1
#2   a    6    1
#3   a    8    1
#4   a  870    1
#5   a   34    2
#6   a   NA    3
#7   b    4    4
#8   b    6    4
#9   b    8    4
#10  b  870    4
#11  b   34    5
#12  b   NA    6
```

Data:

```
df  <- data.frame(ID=rep(c("a","b"), each=6), diff=c(4,6,8,870,34,NA)
                  , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
#   ID diff
#1   a    4
#2   a    6
#3   a    8
#4   a  870
#5   a   34
#6   a   NA
#7   b    4
#8   b    6
#9   b    8
#10  b  870
#11  b   34
#12  b   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution using `ave` + `ifelse`

```
df <- within(df,rank <- ave(diff>14, diff>14,ID,FUN = function(x) ifelse(x,seq(x),+!x)))
```